# Swiping charts?

Tags: java, android, swipe

I am using MPAndroidChart library to make charts for an android application. I would like to make 3-4 charts and want to swipe them. Is it possible to have swipe functionality using MPAndroidChart library and how can I implement such swipe function?

Answer (score 1):

I think by understanding your problem I may suggest two possible ways to do so.

1] Use horizontal recycler view and each row will have a chart to show and to do so create a list with custom model class.

2] Use ViewPager with Fragment:

To create a view pager pass your expected list of graphs and on every getItem create a new Fragment instance and attach it to viewpager.

Pass custom model class as a input values to render your chart through bundle using parcable or serializable interface.

Each fragment will have a chart to show.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) and attach a FragmentStatePagerAdapter

```
public class SomePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
int mNumOfTabs;

public MISPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new LineChartFragment();
        case 1:
            return new BarChartFragment();
        case 2:
            return new PieChartFragment();
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mNumOfTabs;
}}
```

Each Fragment will have its own dataset using which the charts will be drawn.